# Curl command doesn't work in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to upload a JSON file into my noSQL database using a bash script, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

This is the script :

```
test='{"evaluation": "none"}'
test="'$test'"
command="curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/evaluation/$i -d $test"
echo "$command"
$command
```

This is the error :

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/evaluation/0 -d '{"evaluation": "none"}'
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 7
```

When I do the command given in my command line it works fine though.

What is the error here ? Thank you

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store a command in a variable; if you absolutely must have something usable with logging, put the *arguments* in an array.

```
test='{"evaluation": "none"}'
args=( -XPUT localhost9200/test/evaluation/"$i" -d "$test" )
echo "curl ${args[*]}"
curl "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: thank you ! I've been wondering on the problem for a while and this solution works perfectly