# curl command within bash file doesn't work

Tags: bash, curl

I have a main bash script that I want to use to make a HTTP request using `curl`.

The line where `curl` command is executed is like this:

```
echo $(curl -X POST $URL -H \'$HEADERS\' -d \'$data\')
```

When this line runs I get an error:

```
"status":415, "error":"Unsupported Media Type", "message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
```

But if I execute the same line without the `$()` operator, like this:

```
echo curl -X POST $URL -H \'$HEADERS\' -d \'$data\'
```

I'll get something like this as output:

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/employees -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{ "age":"25", "firstName":"Peggy", "lastName":"Ailbert", "role":"Thief" }'
```

That runs perfecty if copied to terminal.

I would like to know what is going wrong with the code.

**NOTES:**

- The variables `$URL` and `$HEADERS` are from a `.conf` and holds constant values:

```
URL="localhost:8080/employees"
HEADERS="Content-type:application/json"
```

- The `$data` variable is built when the main bash runs an holds random values for the keys, like this:

```
{ "age":"59", "firstName":"Lauree", "lastName":"Inna", "role":"Mage" }
```

- I've tried the answer in this question: [Curl command doesn't work in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919951/curl-command-doesnt-work-in-bash-script) but it didn't worked for me.
- The source for the bash script can be found at https://github.com/JeanCHilger/automated-requester/blob/master/post/POST.sh (the 70th line is where I am getting the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have `\'` around your variables. That will put a literal single quote into that argument.

Use double quotes to make a variable expand as a single argument.

```
curl -X POST "$URL" -H "$HEADERS" -d "$data"
```

Comment: How are you setting `$HEADERS`? With `source filename.conf`?

Comment: actually I did what you said and now it worked. Thanks